# Import Error while importing test module in VScode

Tags: pytest, visual-studio-code, test-explorer

In my VScode I have the attached image folder structure and when I am trying to run any test it says Import error while importing test module [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Atdb.jpg)

I my settings.json file I have

```
"terminal.intergarted.env.windows":{PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src"},
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
```

Can anyhelp help what I can do to make my test module import , It seems right now its not able to find the test folder itself .

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Not sure if this is related to your problem, but the setting `"terminal.intergarted.env.windows"` is misspelled (correct: integrated).

Comment: I miss spelled it here not in in my VScode